# Opera browser not recognizing ht-access redirects

Tags: html, opera

I just created a ht-access file to redirect my website to secure SSL connections. The code works on Chrome, Firefox and IE, but Opera refuses to redirect to the https:// pages? I've no idea why?

Here is my (very simple) ht-acces file.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.ateeaday.com.au/$1 [R,L]
```

Any suggestions why opera refuses the redirect? Any advice to improve the code greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Tools -> Prefernences -> Advanced -> Network -> Enable automatic redirect` => is that enabled? Otherwise, just open Dragonfly and let the console tell you why.

Comment: Only issue Dragonfly threw up was an insecure link to a google font. Changed link to https but still Opera throws up the http page. It actually redirects requests for the https page to the http page, so it isn't happy with something. Using Opera 19, can't find if enable automatic redirect is enabled, as I can't find tools . preferences . advanced etc, etc, but I am using Opera pretty much "out of the box" with no modifications to general settings, so assume it is enabled.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot, I'm still an Opera 12.50 user as Opera has refused to make a new Linux version... Lots of changes in between. I'm afraid I can't help you with it further unless I fork out for Windows or MacOS, both of which I refuse to do. Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for your help anyways! Sorry Opera people aren't sharing the love for Linux!